# mysqldump command not working in cron job

Tags: centos, cron, mysql

I am trying to take backup using below bash script scheduled in cron.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello"
while read table
do
/usr/bin/mysqldump -uroot -pxxxxxx CMAYA_RadiusUserLogs $table > sc_back/${table}.sql
done < tables.txt
```

cron is scheduled as below

```
58 16 * * * root /bin/sh -x /backup/call_backup.sh > /backup/backup.log
```

/var/log/cron as below

```
Jul  3 16:27:01  (root) CMD (/bin/sh -x /backup/backup.sh > /backup/backup.log)
```

/backup/backup.log

```
[root@ backup]# cat backup.log
Hello
```

When I execute this same script manually it works properly and put any other command in script it works in cron job.

Comment: i) why are you using `/bin/sh -x script` if your script already has a [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))? ii) Where is `tables.txt`? How is the script supposed to find it?

Answer (score 2):

I have corrected tables.txt path but problem still persists but after redirecting std err 2>&1 it is started working. The reason I found that the warning message "Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure." creates the problem. After this message mysqldump exits in , so I redirected the error and its started working. I observed this after upgrading mysql to 5.6.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello"
while read table
do
touch sc_back/${table}.sql
/usr/bin/mysqldump -uroot -pxxxxx CMAYA_RadiusUserLogs $table > /backup /sc_back/${table}.sql
done < /backup/tables.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the last line of the script you need to enter the full absolute path for the file `tables.txt`, otherwise the cron job cannot find it.

The reason the script works when you launch it manually is that the `tables.txt`file is located into the current directory, so the system has no problem finding it.

Answer (score 0):

When cron executes your script current working directory is cron table's user home directory (apparently /root), while your script with its files is located under /backup. This is why script can't find table.txt and table loop has no iterations.

You should first cd to the script's directory, then execute it, like:

```
58 16 * * * root cd /backup && /bin/sh -x call_backup.sh > backup.log
```